# Inverse Error Function in C

Tags: c, function, inverse

Is it possible to calculate the inverse error function in C?

I can find `erf(x)` in `<math.h>` which calculates the error function, but I can't find anything to do the inverse.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: A little late to the party, but you might want to take a look at: https://gist.github.com/lakshayg/d80172fe5ae3c5d2c2aedb53c250320e (full disclosure: I am the author)

Answer (score 18):

At this time, the ISO C standard math library does not include `erfinv()`, or its single-precision variant `erfinvf()`. However, it is not too difficult to create one's own version, which I demonstrate below with an implementation of `erfinvf()` of reasonable accuracy and performance.

Looking at the [graph of the inverse error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html) we observe that it is highly non-linear and is therefore difficult to approximate with a polynomial. One strategy do deal with this scenario is to "linearize" such a function by compositing it from simpler elementary functions (which can themselves be computed at high performance and excellent accuracy) and a fairly linear function which is more easily amenable to polynomial approximations or rational approximations of low degree.

Here are some approaches to `erfinv` linearization known from the literature, all of which are based on logarithms. Typically, authors differentiate between a main, fairly linear portion of the inverse error function from zero to a switchover point very roughly around 0.9 and a *tail* portion from the switchover point to unity. In the following, log() denotes the natural logarithm,  R() denotes a rational approximation, and P() denotes a polynomial approximation.

A. J. Strecok, "On the Calculation of the Inverse of the Error Function."
*Mathematics of Computation*, Vol. 22, No. 101 (Jan. 1968), pp. 144-158 [(online)](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1968-22-101/S0025-5718-1968-0223070-2/S0025-5718-1968-0223070-2.pdf)

> β(x) = (-log(1-x<sup>2</sup>]))<sup>½</sup>; erfinv(x) = x · R(x<sup>2</sup>) [main]; R(x) · β(x) [tail]

J. M. Blair, C. A. Edwards, J. H. Johnson, "Rational Chebyshev Approximations for the Inverse of the Error Function." *Mathematics of Computation*, Vol. 30, No. 136 (Oct. 1976), pp. 827-830  [(online)](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1976-30-136/S0025-5718-1976-0421040-7/S0025-5718-1976-0421040-7.pdf)

> ξ = (-log(1-x))<sup>-½</sup>; erfinv(x) = x · R(x<sup>2</sup>) [main]; ξ<sup>-1</sup> · R(ξ) [tail]

M. Giles, "Approximating the erfinv function." In *GPU Computing Gems Jade Edition*, pp. 109-116. 2011. [(online)](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/codes/erfinv/gems.pdf)

> w = -log(1-x<sup>2</sup>); s = √w; erfinv(x) = x · P(w) [main]; x · P(s) [tail]

The solution below generally follows the approach by Giles, but simplifies it in not requiring the square root for the tail portion, i.e. it uses two approximations of the type x · P(w). The code takes maximum advantage of the fused multiply-add operation FMA, which is exposed via the standard math functions `fma()` and `fmaf()` in C. Many common compute platforms, such as
IBM Power, Arm64, x86-64, and GPUs offer this operation in hardware. Where no hardware support exists, the use of `fma{f}()` will likely make the code below unacceptably slow as the operation needs to be emulated by the standard math library. Also, functionally incorrect emulations of FMA [are known to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166563/is-my-fma-broken).

The accuracy of the standard math library's logarithm function `logf()` will have some impact on the accuracy of `my_erfinvf()` below. As long as the library provides a faithfully-rounded implementation with error < 1 ulp, the stated error bound should hold and it did for the few libraries I tried. For improved reproducability, I have included my own portable faithfully-rounded implementation, `my_logf()`.

```c
#include <math.h>
float my_logf (float);

/* compute inverse error functions with maximum error of 2.35793 ulp */
float my_erfinvf (float a)
{
    float p, r, t;
    t = fmaf (a, 0.0f - a, 1.0f);
    t = my_logf (t);
    if (fabsf(t) > 6.125f) { // maximum ulp error = 2.35793
        p =              3.03697567e-10f; //  0x1.4deb44p-32 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  2.93243101e-8f); //  0x1.f7c9aep-26 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  1.22150334e-6f); //  0x1.47e512p-20 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  2.84108955e-5f); //  0x1.dca7dep-16 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  3.93552968e-4f); //  0x1.9cab92p-12 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  3.02698812e-3f); //  0x1.8cc0dep-9 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  4.83185798e-3f); //  0x1.3ca920p-8 
        p = fmaf (p, t, -2.64646143e-1f); // -0x1.0eff66p-2 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  8.40016484e-1f); //  0x1.ae16a4p-1 
    } else { // maximum ulp error = 2.35002
        p =              5.43877832e-9f;  //  0x1.75c000p-28 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  1.43285448e-7f); //  0x1.33b402p-23 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  1.22774793e-6f); //  0x1.499232p-20 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  1.12963626e-7f); //  0x1.e52cd2p-24 
        p = fmaf (p, t, -5.61530760e-5f); // -0x1.d70bd0p-15 
        p = fmaf (p, t, -1.47697632e-4f); // -0x1.35be90p-13 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  2.31468678e-3f); //  0x1.2f6400p-9 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  1.15392581e-2f); //  0x1.7a1e50p-7 
        p = fmaf (p, t, -2.32015476e-1f); // -0x1.db2aeep-3 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  8.86226892e-1f); //  0x1.c5bf88p-1 
    }
    r = a * p;
    return r;
}

/* compute natural logarithm with a maximum error of 0.85089 ulp */
float my_logf (float a)
{
    float i, m, r, s, t;
    int e;

    m = frexpf (a, &e);
    if (m < 0.666666667f) { // 0x1.555556p-1
        m = m + m;
        e = e - 1;
    }
    i = (float)e;
    /* m in [2/3, 4/3] */
    m = m - 1.0f;
    s = m * m;
    /* Compute log1p(m) for m in [-1/3, 1/3] */
    r =             -0.130310059f;  // -0x1.0ae000p-3
    t =              0.140869141f;  //  0x1.208000p-3
    r = fmaf (r, s, -0.121484190f); // -0x1.f19968p-4
    t = fmaf (t, s,  0.139814854f); //  0x1.1e5740p-3
    r = fmaf (r, s, -0.166846052f); // -0x1.55b362p-3
    t = fmaf (t, s,  0.200120345f); //  0x1.99d8b2p-3
    r = fmaf (r, s, -0.249996200f); // -0x1.fffe02p-3
    r = fmaf (t, m, r);
    r = fmaf (r, m,  0.333331972f); //  0x1.5554fap-2
    r = fmaf (r, m, -0.500000000f); // -0x1.000000p-1
    r = fmaf (r, s, m);
    r = fmaf (i,  0.693147182f, r); //  0x1.62e430p-1 // log(2)
    if (!((a > 0.0f) && (a <= 3.40282346e+38f))) { // 0x1.fffffep+127
        r = a + a;  // silence NaNs if necessary
        if (a  < 0.0f) r = ( 0.0f / 0.0f); //  NaN
        if (a == 0.0f) r = (-1.0f / 0.0f); // -Inf
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: You sir deserve a beer! Thanks for posting this gem. If you dont mind me asking what tool did you use for this? Sollya

Comment: @nimig18 Thanks for the kind words. Although Sollya is a great tool for generating minimax approximations, here I used my own software, based on the Remez algorithm, to generate the initial approximations, then refined them with a heuristic search similar to simulated annealing. As I recall, the heuristic search took a very long time (**lots** of heating and cooling cycles, so to speak).

Comment: ninja! This is too pro. I've done custom Remez algorithms to define the error on the boundaries, which maybe that's what you did here for the piecewise approximate implementation. But this is where I would have stopped, this annealing process took it to another level of rigor and is very interesting. But something like this [link](https://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/publications/papers/pldi14a.pdf)?

Comment: @nimig18 Based on a quick perusal of the paper: No, they have a different objective and methodology. I create what I consider (based on experience) as a reasonable program structure by hand, then find the best approximation *within that framework* (sequence of operations). One could call it a holistic approach to determining the coefficients of the minimax approximation(s). The flip-side is that I need to re-tune the approximation every time I change the code structure. So a less elegant approach and more brute force.

Comment: How much more/less accurate is your version than the one of Giles? Looking at their paper, they say it may be (they did not calculate) 4 ULP for floats, but wondering if you ran some tests yourself.

Comment: @Azmisov Depends on what platform you build the code and how you compile it. In a quick test using the Intel compiler and its associated library, I see maximum error of about 3.75 ulps.

Answer (score 13):

Quick & dirty, tolerance under +-6e-3. Work based on "A handy approximation for the error function and its inverse" by Sergei Winitzki.

C/C++ CODE:

```
float myErfInv2(float x){
   float tt1, tt2, lnx, sgn;
   sgn = (x < 0) ? -1.0f : 1.0f;

   x = (1 - x)*(1 + x);        // x = 1 - x*x;
   lnx = logf(x);

   tt1 = 2/(PI*0.147) + 0.5f * lnx;
   tt2 = 1/(0.147) * lnx;

   return(sgn*sqrtf(-tt1 + sqrtf(tt1*tt1 - tt2)));
}
```

MATLAB sanity check:

```
clear all,  close all, clc 

x = linspace(-1, 1,10000);
% x = 1 - logspace(-8,-15,1000);

a = 0.15449436008930206298828125;
% a = 0.147;

u = log(1-x.^2);  
u1 = 2/(pi*a) + u/2;    u2 = u/a;
y = sign(x).*sqrt(-u1+sqrt(u1.^2 - u2)); 

f = erfinv(x); axis equal

figure(1);
plot(x, [y; f]); legend('Approx. erf(x)', 'erf(x)')

figure(2);
e = f-y;
plot(x, e);
```

MATLAB Plots:
[image: inverf() Approx vs. Actual]

[image: inverf() Approx Error]

Comment: This was a great find. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Changing the constant from `0.147` to `0.15449436008930206298828125` reduces the maximum absolute error from about 0.005 to about 0.0009 in my tests.

Comment: @nemequ Thank you for adding this, so at first glance this looks like an improvement and maybe it really is when you consider it, but there's something interesting near 1. If you instead change `x = 1 - logspace(-8,-15,100);` in the matlab script then compare the two constants you will see the stability for the original `0.147` is less divergent than the one proposed (i.e. -8e-3 vs. -13e-3). But really this is pedantic, an equal-ripple error this infinitesimally small is impossible. Ill update with your constant.

Comment: Testing C code erff( myErfInv2(x) ) == x for x in (-1, +1), I've found that 0.147 works more precisely than 0.15449436008930206298828125 by an order of magnitude..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a [standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions) implementation in `<math.h>`, but there are other [C math](http://libit.sourceforge.net/math_8c-source.html) libraries that have implement the inverse error function `erfinv(x)`, that you can use.

Comment: Do you know a long double version?

Answer (score 0):

Also quick and dirty: if less precision is allowed than I share my own approximation with the inverse hyperbolic tangent - the parameters are sought by monte carle simulation where all random values are between the range of 0.5 and 1.5:

```
p1 = 1.4872301551536515
p2 = 0.5739159012216655
p3 = 0.5803635928651558

atanh( p^( 1 / p3 ) ) / p2 )^( 1 / p1 )
```

This comes from the algebraic reordering of my erf function approximation with the hyperbolic tangent, where the RMSE error is 0.000367354 for x between 1 and 4:

```
tanh( x^p1 * p2 )^p3
```

Comment: Please restate in C syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another method that uses the fast-converging Newton-Rhapson method, which is an iterative method to find the root of a function. It starts with an initial guess and then iteratively improves the guess by using the derivative of the function. The Newton-Raphson method requires the function, its derivative, an initial guess and a stopping criteria.

In this case, the function we are trying to find the root of is `erf(x) - x`. And the derivative of this function is `2.0 / sqrt(pi) * exp(-x**2)`. The initial guess is the input value for `x`. The stopping criteria is a tolerance value, in this case it's `1.0e-16`. Here is the code:

```
/*
============================================
 Compile and execute with:
    $ gcc inverf.c -o inverf -lm
    $ ./inverf
============================================
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double x, result, fx, dfx, dx, xold;
    double tolerance = 1.0e-16;
    double pi = 4.0 * atan(1.0);
    int iteration, i;

    // input value for x
    printf("Calculator for inverse error function.\n");
    printf("Enter the value for x: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    // check the input value is between -1 and 1
    if (x < -1.0 || x > 1.0) {
        printf("Invalid input, x must be between -1 and 1.");
        return 0;
    }

    // initial guess
    result = x;
    xold = 0.0;
    iteration = 0;

    // iterate until the solution converges
    do {
        xold = result;
        fx = erf(result) - x;
        dfx = 2.0 / sqrt(pi) * exp(-pow(result, 2.0));
        dx = fx / dfx;

        // update the solution
        result = result - dx;

        iteration = iteration + 1;
    } while (fabs(result - xold) >= tolerance);

    // output the result
    printf("The inverse error function of %lf is %lf\n", x, result);
    printf("Number of iterations: %d\n", iteration);

    return 0;
}
```

In the terminal it should look something like this:

> ```
>  Calculator for inverse error function.
>  Enter the value for x: 0.5
>  The inverse error function of 0.500000 is 0.476936
>  Number of iterations: 5
> ```