# Companion to hypot()

Tags: c, algorithm, geometry

The `hypot` function, introduced into C in the 1999 revision of the language, calculates the hypotenuse of a right triangle given the other sides as arguments, but with care taken to avoid the over/underflow which would result from the naive implementation as

```
double hypot(double a, double b)
{
  return sqrt(a*a + b*b);
}
```

I find myself with the need for companion functionality: given a side and the hypotenuse of a triangle, find the third side (avoiding under/overflow).  I can think of a few ways to do this, but wondered if there was an existing "best practice"?

My target is Python, but really I'm looking for algorithm pointers.

---

Thanks for the replies. In case anyone is interested in the result, my C99 implementation can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/jjg/cathetus) and a Python version [here](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/blob/master/hypothesis-python/src/hypothesis/internal/cathetus.py), part of the [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.works/) project.

Comment: How big are these triangles that people are measuring, that people need to avoid overflow? The observable universe is less than 9e26 meters across.

Comment: Be aware that you can get into deep numerical trouble when the angle between the two given sides of the triangle is small. Math says, that `b = sqrt(h*h - a*a)`, but if `h` is only slightly larger than `a`, the resulting `b` will have no precision whatsoever. I think, it's best to avoid this calculation if you can.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : this for a testing library, no physics involved

Comment: [Apple’s implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/Intel/xmm_hypot.c.auto.html) does not seem to do anything particularly tricky. For `float` and `double`, it uses more precision. For `long double`, it breaks things into cases handled in their own ways.

Comment: Note: Python does not have a strict floating-point specification. It loosely inherits the properties of the platform it is implemented on. This makes it problematic to implement any definitive solution for Python. You may want to assume IEEE 754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point, but that should be clearly documented in the code.

Comment: Re: [my C99 implementation](https://github.com/jjgreen/cathetus). suggest changing `return sqrt(h - a) * sqrt(h/2 + a/2) * sqrt(2);` --> `return sqrt(h - a) * sqrt(h/4 + a/4) * 2;` to reduce imprecision of multiplying by the approximate square-root of 2.

Comment: @EricPostpischil [Apple’s implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/Intel/xmm_hypot.c.auto.html) in `hypot()` has `return (float)(X + Y);`.  What might the cast to `float` accomplish vs. the more expected  `return (double)(X + Y);`?  Is it somehow faster, smaller code?

Comment: @chux: I have three guesses. (a) The cast is intended to ensure a true conversion to `float` occurs (rounding the value and not retaining the excess precision the C standard generally allows) as specified in 5.2.4.2.2 9. The standard says a `return` converts as if by assignment, and assignments also discard excess precision, but one might read 6.8.6.4 as ambiguous on that point. (b) The cast is intended to ensure a true conversion because compilers might not do it in a `return` even if the intent of the standard is to require that.…

Comment: …  (c) Habit of writing explicit conversions in floating-point code, where they may be necessary in intermediate expressions (to ensure the desired precision is used). You could ask the author [Ian Ollmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3166255/ian-ollmann), but that code is over 12 years old, so memory may be fuzzy.

Comment: @chux, that's a really neat idea, thanks!

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for your review - I suppose I could post a question if @Ian Ollmann codes not comment in a month.   As that code has at least one of `X,Y` as a NaN - precision issues do not appear to apply. I'm leaning toward a cut/paste oops from `hypotf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is factorize:

```
b = sqrt(h*h - a*a) = sqrt((h-a)*(h+a))
```

We have not only avoided some overflow, but also gained accuracy.

If any factor is close to `1E+154 = sqrt(1E+308)` (max with IEEE 754 64 bits float) then we must also avoid overflow:

```
sqrt((h-a)*(h+a)) = sqrt(h-a) * sqrt(h+a)
```

This case is very unlikely, so the two `sqrt`'s are justified, even if its slower than just a `sqrt`.

Notice that if `h ~ 5E+7 * a` then `h ~ b` which means that there are not enough digits to represent `b` as different from `h`.

Comment: For real triangles, `h >= a >= 0` holds.  Yet depending on computational paths of forming `h`, I could see corner cases where `h` is very close in value to `a` and maybe even less by a ULP.  Then `sqrt(h-a)` leads to `sqrt(negative)`.  This good answer may benefit with tests to cope with that and pathological `h,a` combinations.

Answer (score 4):

This answer assumes a platform that uses floating-point arithmetic compliant with IEEE-754 (2008) and provides fused multiply-add (FMA) capability. Both conditions are met by common architectures such as x86-64, ARM64, and Power. FMA is exposed in ISO C99 and later C standards as a standard math function `fma()`. On hardware that does not provide an FMA instruction, this requires emulation, which could be slow and [functionally deficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166563/is-my-fma-broken).

Mathematically, the length of one leg (cathetus) in a right triangle, given the length of the hypotenuse and the other leg, is simply computed as `√(h²-a²)`, where `h` is the length of the hypotenuse. But when computed with finite-precision floating-point arithmetic, we face two problems: Overflow or underflow to zero may take place when computing the squares, and subtraction of the squares gives rise to [subtractive cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) when the squares have similar magnitude.

The first issue is easily taken care of by scaling by 2<sup>n</sup> such that the term larger in magnitude is moved closer to unity. As subnormal numbers may be involved, this cannot be accomplished by manipulating the exponent field, as there may be a need to normalize / denormalize. But we can compute the required scale factors by exponent field bit manipulation, the multiply by the factors. We know that the hypotenuse has to be longer or the same length as the given leg for non-exceptional cases, so can base the scaling on that argument.

Dealing with subtractive cancellation is harder, but we are lucky that computation very similar to our computation h²-a² occurs in other important problems. For example, the grandmaster of floating-point computation looked into the accurate computation of the discriminant of the quadratic formula, `b²-4ac`:

William Kahan, "On the Cost of Floating-Point Computation Without Extra-Precise Arithmetic", Nov. 21, 2004 ([online](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Qdrtcs.pdf))

More recently, French researchers addressed the more general case of the difference of two products, `ad-bc`:

Claude-Pierre Jeannerod, Nicolas Louvet, Jean-Michel Muller, "Further analysis of Kahan's algorithm for the accurate computation of 2 x 2 determinants." *Mathematics of Computation*, Vol. 82, No. 284, Oct. 2013, pp. 2245-2264 ([online](https://hal.inria.fr/ensl-00649347/en))

The FMA-based algorithm in the second paper computes the difference of two products with a proven maximum error of 1.5 [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place). With this building block, we arrive at the straightforward ISO C99 implementation of the cathetus computation below. A maximum error of 1.2 ulp was observed in one billion random trials as determined by comparing with the results from an arbitrary-precision library:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

uint64_t __double_as_uint64 (double a)
{
    uint64_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

double __uint64_as_double (uint64_t a)
{
    double r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

/*
  diff_of_products() computes a*b-c*d with a maximum error < 1.5 ulp

  Claude-Pierre Jeannerod, Nicolas Louvet, and Jean-Michel Muller, 
  "Further Analysis of Kahan's Algorithm for the Accurate Computation 
  of 2x2 Determinants". Mathematics of Computation, Vol. 82, No. 284, 
  Oct. 2013, pp. 2245-2264
*/
double diff_of_products (double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    double w = d * c;
    double e = fma (-d, c, w);
    double f = fma (a, b, -w);
    return f + e;
}

/* compute sqrt (h*h - a*a) accurately, avoiding spurious overflow */
double my_cathetus (double h, double a)
{
    double fh, fa, res, scale_in, scale_out, d, s;
    uint64_t expo;

    fh = fabs (h);
    fa = fabs (a);

    /* compute scale factors */
    expo = __double_as_uint64 (fh) & 0xff80000000000000ULL;
    scale_in = __uint64_as_double (0x7fc0000000000000ULL - expo);
    scale_out = __uint64_as_double (expo + 0x0020000000000000ULL);

    /* scale fh towards unity */
    fh = fh * scale_in;
    fa = fa * scale_in;

    /* compute sqrt of difference of scaled arguments, avoiding overflow */
    d = diff_of_products (fh, fh, fa, fa);
    s = sqrt (d);

    /* reverse previous scaling */
    res = s * scale_out;

    /* handle special arguments */
    if (isnan (h) || isnan (a)) {
        res = h + a;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, I dropped your implementation above into my version of the function, just to see if it passed the unit tests.  Some [fail](https://gitlab.com/jjg/cathetus/-/jobs/331096560), but those are to do with inf/nan and infeasible arguments.  The code is [here](https://gitlab.com/jjg/cathetus/tree/njuffa).

Comment: @jjg The desired specifications for special case handling were not clear to me from the question, so I simply chose what seemed reasonable to me :-) Special case handling could be adjusted to taste by anyone opting to use this algorithm. I was mostly focused on *accuracy* and performance here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming IEEE 754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point, I would consider an algorithm such as:

- Set *s* (for scale) to be 2<sup>−512</sup> if 2<sup>100</sup> ≤ *a*, 2<sup>+512</sup> if *a* < 2<sup>−100</sup>, and 1 otherwise.
- Let *a*' be *a*•*s* and *b*' be *b*•*s*.
- Compute sqrt(*a*'•*a*' − *b*'•*b*') / *s*.

Notes about the reasoning:

- If *a* is large (or small), multiplying by *s* decreases (or increases) the values so that the square of *a*' remains in the floating-point range.
- The scale factor is a power of two, so multiplying and dividing by it is exact in binary floating-point.
- *b* is necessarily smaller than (or equal to) *a*, or else we return NaN, which is appropriate. In the case where we are increasing *a*, no error occurs; *b*' and *b*'•*b*' remain within range. In the case where we are decreasing *a*, *b*' may lose precision or become zero if *b* is small, but then *b* is so much smaller than *a* that the computed result cannot depend on the precise value of *b* in any case.
- I partitioned the floating-point range into three intervals because two will not suffice. For example, if you set *s* to be 2<sup>−512</sup> if 1 ≤ *a* and 2<sup>+512</sup> otherwise, then 1 will scale to 2<sup>−512</sup> and then square to 2<sup>−1024</sup>, at which point a *b* slightly under 1 will be losing precision relevant to the result. But if you use a less-magnitude power for *s*, such as 2<sup>−511</sup>, then 2<sup>1023</sup> will scale to 2<sup>512</sup> and square to 2<sup>1024</sup>, which is out of bounds. Therefore, we need different scale factors for *a* = 1 and *a* = 2<sup>1023</sup>. Similarly, *a* = 2<sup>−1049</sup> needs a scale factor that would be too large for *a* = 1. So three are needed.
- Division is notoriously slow, so one might want to multiply by a prepared *s*<sup>−1</sup> rather than dividing by *s*.

Comment: Thanks -- I had such a scaling in mind as part of the solution, but had not yet looked at the details

Answer (score 0):

`hypot` has its idiosyncrasies in that it's one of a *very select few* C standard library functions that does **not** propagate `NaN`! (Another one is `pow` for the case where the first argument being 1.)

Setting that aside, I'd be inclined to write merely

```
returns sqrt(h * h - a * a); // h is the hypotenuse
```

as the body of the function, and burden the caller with checking the inputs. If you can't do that then follow the specification of `hypot` faithfully.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am the caller, so this is not an option.  The inputs _will_ be extreme, by design of the application.

Comment: @jjg In that case, I'd follow the hypot spec faithfully, and add stub functions to both to make extra checks.

Comment: This changed my thinking about "what is a NaN", previously I took it literally, but now I think "not a specific number", then `hypot(NAN, INF) == INF` makes sense, if one non-hypotenuse side of a triangle is infinite then the hypotenuse is infinite whatever the other non-hypotenuse side is.