# How advantageous is using fused multiply-accumulate for double-precision?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, x86-64, fma

I am trying to understand if is advantageous using *std::fma* with double arguments by looking at the assembly code that is generated, I am using the flag "-O3", and I am comparing the assembly for this two routines:

```
#include <cmath>
#define FP_FAST_FMAF

float test_1(const double &a, const double &b, const double &c ){
    return a*b + c;
}
float test_2(const double &a, const double &b, const double &c ){
    return std::fma(a,b,c);
}
```

Using the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KhrchV) tools, this is the assembly  generated for the two routines:

```
test_1(double const&, double const&, double const&):
        movsd     xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdi]                         #5.12
        mulsd     xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi]                         #5.14
        addsd     xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdx]                         #5.18
        cvtsd2ss  xmm0, xmm0                                    #5.18
        ret                                                     #5.18
test_2(double const&, double const&, double const&):
        push      rsi                                           #7.65
        movsd     xmm0, QWORD PTR [rdi]                         #8.12
        movsd     xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsi]                         #8.12
        movsd     xmm2, QWORD PTR [rdx]                         #8.12
        call      fma                                           #8.12
        cvtsd2ss  xmm0, xmm0                                    #8.12
        pop       rcx                                           #8.12
        ret
```

And the assembly does not change by using the latest version available for either icc or gcc. what is puzzling for me regarding the performance of the two routines is that, while for test_1 there is only one memory operation ( *movsd* ), there are three for test_2, and considering the latency for memory operations is between one and two orders of magnitude larger than the latency for floating-point operations, test_1 shall be more performant. Thus, in which situations is advisable using std::fma? What is mistaken in my hypothesis?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but if you remove the references on `a`, `b`, and `c`, then the assembly for `test_2` becomes just a `jmp fma` call, and `test_1` becomes 3 instructions. (Example on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ewzbF4))

Comment: the `-O3` option does not know anything about your instruction set. I just added `-march=native` with both compilers and your two functions become equivalent (and use the `vfmadd213sd`instruction). By the way, the `mulsd` and `addsd` instructions *contain* the move operation (ie retrieve data from memory).

Comment: all three have to perform memory cycles as your code dictates, the same number.  but by using a function, test_2 has the potential to be slower.  If the optimizer can recognize a multiply-accumulate and is programmed to use it then calling a function will always be slower than having the compiler generate it.  if it cant optimize to that then it could go either way.  if you work off of addresses to things and not the things themselves, then you are not interested in performance.  so how the math is done is secondary.

Comment: Your title is misleading implying you want to use a specific instruction but your implementation for the most part tosses out performance gains you might see by saving an instruction.  the question should have been more like what gains are there in using a function vs code being generated inline.

Comment: If these are handled inline instead of in a function call, lots of differences might happen -- avoiding memory fetches, reordering of instructions, overlapping, etc.

Comment: See also [Is my fma() broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42166563/2410359).

Comment: re: latency: L1d load-use latency is 5 to 6 cycles (for SIMD loads) on current CPUs, which happens to be about the same as FMA latency.  The memory reference is your own fault for passing by reference (pointers to memory) instead of by value (in XMM registers).  https://godbolt.org/z/DFgKMz shows that GCC will (by default) even *contract* `a*b + c` into an FMA instruction, with its default setting of `-ffp-contract=fast`, when it's available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is related to the number of memory operations only, it is important to note that `mulsd` and `addsd` are also memory operations in your example. Memory operations are indicated by the square brackets around the register name, not the assembly mnemonic itself.

If you're still curious if it's advantageous to use `std::fma`, the answer is probably "it depends."

When you are analyzing performance by looking at assembly, it is almost essential to give the compiler at least some information about your target architecture. `std::fma` uses hardware FMA instructions if they are available on the target architecture, so whether or not `std::fma` improves performance in general is not really an answerable question.

If you [specify `-mfma` in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ckAKbr), the compiler has some information that it can leverage to generate more efficient code. You can also specify `-march=[your architecture]` which will automatically set `-mfma` for you if it is supported.

---

Additionally, there's a whole other can of worms about the slight differences in the results from `std::fma` and `(a*b)+c` due to the way rounding is handled with floating point numbers. `std::fma` only rounds once during the two floating point operations, while `(a*b)+c` might<sup>[1]</sup> do `a*b`, store the result in 64 bits, add `c` to this value and then store the result in 64 bits.

If you want to minimize floating point arithmetic error in your calculations, `std::fma` is probably a better choice because it guarantees you will only have precious bits stripped away from your precious floating point numbers once.

---

<sup>[1] <sup>Whether or not this extra rounding happens depends on your compiler, your optimization settings and your architecture settings:
[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KXvAQN) examples for msvc, gcc, icc, clang</sup></sup>

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the memory references are the OP's fault for passing by reference instead of by value (in XMM registers already).

Comment: But yes, if `std::fma` can inline to a single instruction, it's typically better for throughput and sometimes latency.  (Although gcc will already contract mul/add into an FMA, and clang has an option to do that aggressively across statements like GCC's default, so you often don't need to manually use `std::fma`.)  But without hardware FMA support, `std::fma` is massively slower.