# How does -march native affect floating point accuracy?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, x86-64, precision

The code I work on has a substantial amount of floating point arithmetic in it. We have test cases that record the output for given inputs and verify that we don't change the results too much. I had it suggested that I enable -march native to improve performance. However, with that enabled we get test failures because the results have changed. Do the instructions that will be used because of access to more modern hardware enabled by -march native reduce the amount of floating point error? Increase the amount of floating point error? Or a bit of both? Fused multiply add should reduce the amount of floating point error but is that typical of instructions added over time? Or have some instructions been added that while more efficient are less accurate?

The platform I am targeting is x86_64 Linux. The processor information according to `/proc/cpuinfo` is:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6152 CPU @ 2.10GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x2006a0a
cpu MHz     : 2799.999
cache size  : 30976 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 44
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 22
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti intel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req pku ospke md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs taa itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 4200.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: The issue could be undefined behaviour. I recommend experimenting to find out which one of `-mXXX` enabled by `-march native` causes the problem.

Comment: That is a good suggestion @eerorika. While I certainly hope it is not UB (I've tried running with UB san and address sanitizer recently), looking at the impact of smaller changes will probably shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: but you do not use `<fenv.h>` stuff, right?

Comment: Note: FMA sometimes [stink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166563/is-my-fma-broken).

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин no `<fenv.h>` aside from during testing I sometimes call `feenableexcept(FE_INVALID);` to detect when we produce a NaN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of FMA can both decrease and increase error, *both* of those may result in a testcase failing, depending on how the test works. FMA improves error "locally", but the effect may be the opposite when put in a wider context.

For example, `a * c - b * d` (determinant of a 2x2 matrix) famously gives some (usually minor) trouble when FMA-contracted. Without FMA, the subtraction has the potential to eliminate the rounding error, if it is the same on both sides. That does not always happen, but it can happen when `a * c = b * d` which is of special interest because that means the determinant should be zero. Without FMA the result would actually be zero, with FMA it won't be.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double determinant(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    return a * c - b * d;
}

int main()
{
    volatile double a = M_PI;
    double x = determinant(a, a, a, a);
    printf("%E\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

This program, compiled by GCC 11.2 with optimizations enabled and FMA allowed, [does not print zero](https://godbolt.org/z/153fh8EGE), but something on the order of 1E-16.

Some variants of an "is this result close enough"-test in a unit-test would conclude that this result is, relative to zero, extremely wrong. Another way to look at it though, is that if one of the inputs changed by just 1 ULP, that would have introduced an error on the order of 1E-15, which is even worse.

Most special/new instructions either don't affect accuracy or are by default restricted. For example `addsubpd` and `haddpd` (from SSE3) are just equivalents of what would have cost more code before, and `roundpd` (from SSE4.1) is by default only used in ways that don't affect results (using `roundpd` for `floor` and `ceil` is safe, ironically using it for `round` itself is non-trivial due to the different halfway rounding).

Comment: If this expression contraction is undesired, there's an option `-ffp-contract=off` to disable it. In this case the output of the example here is the same (zero) between e.g. `-march=haswell -O3 -ffp-contract=off -mfpmath=sse` and `-march=pentium4 -O3 -mfpmath=sse`, but is nonzero for `-march=haswell -O3 -mfpmath=sse`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bxY7Esfzs compiler explorer link for the given example.

Answer (score 7):

`-march native` means `-march $MY_HARDWARE`. <strike>We have no idea what hardware you have.</strike> For you, that would be `-march=skylake-avx512` (SkyLake SP) The results could be reproduced by specifying your hardware architecture explicitly.

It's quite possible that the errors will **decrease** with more modern instructions, specifically Fused-Multiply-and-Add (FMA). This is the operation a*b+c, but rounded once instead of twice. That saves one rounding error.

Comment: Your comment about the FMA is the kind of thing I was hoping to find out about. I was aware that this kind of operation is likely to decrease error. Is that typical of instructions added over time? Or have some of the instructions added improved speed at the cost of accuracy?

Comment: @BowieOwens: Well, Intel famously messed up `FDIV` once, so there's that. More seriously, the benchmark for FP accuracy is IEEE754. But it's notoriously slow, especially in corner cases. `-ffast-math` explicitly trades that accuracy for speed. Another example of that tradeoff is the new `BFLOAT16` format in AVX-512, which is not the IEEE754 16-bit float but one that's optimized for AI (specifically, neural network matrix multiplication)

Comment: @Bowen: In case it's not clear to anyone, the FDIV bug wasn't trading accuracy for speed, it was just some kind of transcription error in the hardware lookup tables for the estimate before refinement steps.  All IEEE-754 "basic" operations, add/sub/div/mul/sqrt (and FMA), are all required to be "correctly rounded": rounding error <= 0.5ulp.  The legacy x87 `fsin` / `FYL2X` and so on probably haven't changed on Intel CPUs, and if anything AVX-512 probably increased `rcpps` accuracy.  (Or kept it the same, if it doesn't match AVX-512 [`vrcp14ps`/pd](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vrcp14ps).)