# Need to calculate the complex log of a double precision float

Tags: c++, c, math, floating-point, complex-numbers

I tried computing the real part of clog(a + i*b) using the following approach

> Consider 'x' to be the complex number. x = a + i*b Let z be the
> complex log of x.
>
> real(x)  = 0.5 * log(a^2 + b^2)

This approach gives a huge error in terms of ULP for values between 0.5 and 1.0 especially.

I tried other approaches to avoid squaring of both the real and imaginary parts such as

> Let t = b / a; real(x) = log(a) + 0.5 * log1p(t*t)

The error continued to persist with this approach as well.
I understand that the error is likely from the squaring of a and b and hence I tried using `fma()` operations to get the error due to the squaring of 'a' and 'b'

> Let a2 = a * a
> b2 = b * b
>
> err_a2 = fma(a,a, -a2)
>
> err_b2 = fma(b,b,-b2)

I then tried `0.5 * log(((err_a1 + err_b2) + a2) + b2)` to get the real value of the complex log of x.

But the result is still inaccurate.

How can I compute `log(sqrt(a^2 + b^2))` accurately (error within 2 ULP). I think I need to compute the square root of `a^2 + b^2` in higher precision at a higher precision but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: If you want a better precision that what the standard library offers, you could try to use a multi-precision library like [gmp](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Code could use `double real_part = clog(x)`.

Comment: It seems to be a hard problem in general, and I don't know of any solution not involving  calculating intermediate results at higher precision. The case `a = 0x1.fffffe0000010p-12`, `b = 0x1.fffffc0000040p-1` is an example of how bad things can get: the correctly rounded answer in this case is tiny, around `3.7e-37` (`0x1p-121`), but most algorithms have a hard time producing anything other than `0.0`, which is many billions of ULPs away.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for posting a challenging case.  I [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70943599/2410359) made it.

Comment: Similar catastrophic cancellation occurs with z-1 around z=1.

Comment: Please explain how you observe the "huge error", for example with numerical cases.

Comment: For example, x = 0.70832094846615412 + i * 0.70576270714467548, the result using the approach discussed is -9.0225724105068384e-05 which off by around 886 ULPs. The correctly rounded result is -9.0225724105080397e-05

Comment: @JosephArnold "The correctly rounded result is -9.0225724105080_397e-05" --> `double` encoding typically allows for values of -9.0225724105080_392e-05 and the next nearest 
-9.0225724105080_405e-05, but not -9.0225724105080_397e-05.  How is the suggested correct answer the correct _rounded_ one?

Answer (score 5):

`sqrt(a^2 + b^2)` is just `std::hypot(a,b)`. With a bit of luck, that's already precise.

Answer (score 5):

> ... calculate the complex log of a double ...

Code could use `double real_part = (double) clog(x)`.

---

To calculate the real part of a *complex log of a double* without using `clog(x)` near `|x| == 1.0`, consider using `log1p()`<sup>*1</sup> to form a better precision result.

The core issue is `|x| - 1.0` can suffer severe loss of precision and this is the first step in determining `log()`.

`0.5 * log(a^2 + b^2)` is mathematically like `0.5 * logp1(a^2 + b^2 - 1)`.  When `|x|` is near 1.0 and `|a| > |b|`, use `0.5 * logp1((a-1)*(a+1) + b^2)`.  This subtracts the 1.0 from `|a|` exactly and *retains precision* with `(a-1)*(a+1) + b^2`.  This differs from subtracting 1.0 from `x` as calculation of `x` has already lost important precession.

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define root2 1.4142135623730950488016887242097

double clog_real(double a, double b) {
  double real_x;
  double h = hypot(a, b);
  // |x| near 1.0?
  if (h >= root2 / 2 && h < root2) {
    // Subtract 1 from the larger part
    if (fabs(a) > fabs(b)) {
      real_x = 0.5 * log1p((a - 1) * (a + 1) + b * b);
    } else {
      real_x = 0.5 * log1p((b - 1) * (b + 1) + a * a);
      // or (here and like-wise above IF you have a good fma())
      real_x = 0.5 * log1p(fma(a, a, (b - 1) * (b + 1)));
    }
  } else {
    real_x = log(h);
  }
  return real_x;
}

int main() {
  double a = 0x1.fffffe0000010p-12 * 2;
  double b = 0x1.fffffc0000040p-1;
  printf("%g %g\n", a, b);
  complex double c = a + csqrt(-1) * b;
  printf("%g\n", (double) clog(c));
  printf("%g\n", clog_real(a, b));
}
```

Output

```
0.000976562 1
3.57628e-07
3.57628e-07
```

---

Re: "I tried using `fma()` ..." --> Some `fma()` are [low quality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42172145/2410359).

---

<sup>*1</sup> The `log1p` functions compute the base-e (natural) logarithm of 1 plus the argument.

Comment: Assuming your `fma` is correct, is `(a - 1) * (a + 1)` ever better than `fma(a,a,-1.0)`?

Comment: As `|a|` is in the [.707 ... 1.414] range, `(a - 1) * (a + 1)` is certainly 2 or less ULP off.  `fma(a,a,-1.0)` should be within 0.5 ULP but may be [worse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42172145/2410359).

Comment: The approach still gives the result that are off by a few hundred ULPs for values close to 1. For example, x = 0.70832094846615412 i * 0.70576270714467548, the result is -9.0225724105068384e-05 which off by around 886 ULPs. The correctly rounded result is -9.0225724105080397e-05.

Comment: @JosephArnold As mentioned in the answer, some `fma()` are of low quality. It may be that yours is too.  Try again without `real_x = 0.5 * log1p(fma(a, a, (b - 1) * (b + 1)));`.  With `clog_real(0.70576270714467548, 0.70832094846615412)`, I get -9.0225724105080392e-05 which is 0 ULP from -9.0225724105080397e-05 once the later number is converted to the closest `double`.  BTW, what is the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` on your machine?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica FLT_EVAL_METHOD is 0 in my machine. Had already tried real_x = 0.5 * log1p(fma(a, a, (b - 1) * (b + 1))) but the accuracy did not improve.

Comment: @JosephArnold On my machine `FLT_EVAL_METHOD==2`, Iikely `(b - 1) * (b + 1) + a * a` is taking advantage of `long double` math.  To be clear, I was suggesting to _not_ use `0.5 * log1p(fma(a, a, (b - 1) * (b + 1)))`.  Perhaps later I will try to force `double` math` and test.

Comment: I just looked up the implementation of [`clog`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=math/s_clog_template.c) in `libm`. I guess the most important difference to your solution is that (when necessary) they call a specialized [`__x2y2m1`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/x2y2m1.c#l58) method to calculate `x*x+y*y - 1` with high precision, by splitting the products in halves and adding everything by split additions.

Comment: I tried something similar by using Dekker's multiplication algorithm where you can compute the error that arises in multiplying x and y. r1 + r2 = x * y where r2 is the error. I used the approach for squaring both x and y and then adding up the errors first and then then the squares of x and y. Need to investigate the GLIBC's method further.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `log(sqrt(a*a + b*b))` ?  Normally, the square root has the opposite effect of the square, so probably if you try to calculate it you will make the `log` of a better suited number.

Anyway, to calculate logarithms of numbers close to 1.0, you can probably calculate the derivatives of `log(z + 1)` for `z == 0` and you will get a better approach, as the function is analitic in the circle of radius < 0.5 and so, you will get a good taylor approximation.  This approximation is written below (thanks to Wolfram alpha)

```
log(1+x) ~= x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - x^4/4 + ... (-1)^(n)*x^(n+1)/(n+1) + O(x^(n+2))
```

This is a series that converges absolutely on an open circle of radius 1, so to calculate values close to 1 or the logarithm is well suited (indeed, it is what is used in many places).

Of course, if you want to solve this in the complex plane, you need to operate the calculation as complex numbers.

Comment: The computation of log is quite accurate (within 1 ULP). The error is probably from the squaring of the real and imaginary terms and the subsequent square root operation. When I tested the log() routine for values close to 1, the results were quite accurate.

Comment: @JosephArnold, when you square a floating point number, you lose half the significand in relative precision, but if you square root it again, you recover it.  This is why I recommended to square root before log().  Anyway, the Taylor series will help you, if you do the calculation of it in complex.  Or, as suggested, use the `clog()` funcion.  It is there for you :)

Comment: BTW being under 1ULP is not going to be possible, without the help of a better precision calculator... :)