# Computing the inverse of the complementary error function, erfcinv(), in C

Tags: c, algorithm, floating-point

ISO C99 introduced the `erf()` and `erfc()` functions along with their precision-specific analogues, but inexplicably didn't add their inverses as well. The inverse of the complementary error function, `erfcinv`, in particular is useful in statistical and probability computations, for example as a building block for the inverse of the CDF of the standard normal distribution, `normcdfinv`.

I checked the [document archive](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) of the ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG14 C working group and there is currently still no support for `erfcinv()` in ISO C18, nor do there appear to be any plans to add it in ISO C2x which is currently being worked on.

C programmers are left to create their own implementations. Computing `erfcinv()` accurately is challenging, and while mathematically `erfcinv (x) = erfinv (1 - x)`, this has poor numerical properties in finite-precision floating-point arithmetic when `x` is close to zero. Achieving a 4 ulp error bound, identical to the specification of the LA profile in Intel's vector math library seems a reasonable accuracy goal. It would also be advantageous if the computation allows for copious use of the fused multiply-add operation (FMA) provided by common processor architectures, such as x86-64, ARM64, PowerPC, and GPUs. Finally, it would be useful if the algorithm is amenable to the use of fast reciprocal or reciprocal square root computation available with some architectures.

Years ago, I identified a suitable candidate in a paper in the Journal of Applied Crystallography. With pure single-precision computation, use of FMA and fast reciprocal, I was able to achieve a maximum error of 3.18707 ulp. Only belatedly did I discover that the paper's implementation was based on a C translation of a Fortran subroutine MERFI used by ACM algorithm 602:

Theodore Fessler, William F. Ford, David A. Smith, "HURRY: An Acceleration Algorithm for Scalar Sequences and Series", *ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software*, Vol. 9, No. 3, September 1983, 
pp. 355-357 ([online](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/356044.356051))

Unfortunately, [netlib's software package](http://netlib.org/toms/602.gz) for algorithm 602 shows a copyright notice for MERFI: "1978 BY IMSL, INC. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED" along with the explicitly stated restriction that IMSL code may not be extracted for use in other software development.

What would be a good algorithm for the implementation of single-precision `erfcinvf()`, under consideration of the design goals stated above?

Comment: Is your concern the copyright issue? Copyright does not cover algorithms; it covers specific implementations.

Comment: Another implementation of the same algorithm is not a derivative work. The way you avoid concern that it might be (i.e. might not be independent) is by having an independent party read the original and document the algorithm in a high level form, then having someone else implement based on that documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some while ago, I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743348/780717) showing how one can program an accurate and efficient single-precision implementation of the inverse error function `erfinvf()` in C. While numerical issues prevent us from computing `erfcinvf` from `erfinvf` over its entire supported input domain [0,2], we can re-use on of the core approximations in the previous answer for `erfcinvf()` in the central region [2.1875e-3, 1.998125] with a simple transformation to the input arguments. This adds less than half an [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of error.

With regard to the computation of the `erfcinvf()` tails we observe that functional
symmetry allows us to limit our approximation to [0, 2.1875e-3) and that for this interval `erfcinv(x)` is very roughly `sqrt (-log(x))`. Using this to transform the input arguments results in a function that is reasonably easy to approximate with a polynomial. The minimax approximation can be crafted with the help of the Remez algorithm (as I have done here) or with common mathematical software like Maple or Mathematica.

On most platforms, `sqrtf()` maps directly to a hardware instruction that computes a correctly-rounded square root according to IEEE-754, or an equivalent software emulation. There is typically more variability between implementations of `logf()`, so in the exemplary C code below I have added my own implementation `my_logf()` to aid reproducability. However, any faithfully-rounded implementation of `logf()`, i.e. one with an error bound of 1 ulp, should result in very similar accuracy as in the `erfcinvf()` code below, which achieves a 3.13 ulp error bound. In addition to the plain C implementation, I am also demonstrating how to utilize the reciprocal and reciprocal square root capabilities of SSE for the implementation of `erfcinvf()`.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define PORTABLE  (1)

float my_logf (float a);
#if !PORTABLE
#include "immintrin.h"
float sse_recipf (float a);
float sse_rsqrtf (float a);
#endif // !PORTABLE

/* Compute inverse of the complementary error function. For the central region,
   re-use the polynomial approximation for erfinv. For the tail regions, use an
   approximation based on the observation that erfcinv(x) is very approximately
   sqrt(-log(x)).

   PORTABLE=1 max. ulp err. = 3.12017
   PORTABLE=0 max. ulp err. = 3.13523
*/
float my_erfcinvf (float a)
{
    float r;

    if ((a >= 2.1875e-3f) && (a <= 1.998125f)) { // max. ulp err. = 2.77667
        float p, t;
        t = fmaf (-a, a, a + a);
        t = my_logf (t);
        p =              5.43877832e-9f;  //  0x1.75c000p-28 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  1.43286059e-7f); //  0x1.33b458p-23 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  1.22775396e-6f); //  0x1.49929cp-20 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  1.12962631e-7f); //  0x1.e52bbap-24 
        p = fmaf (p, t, -5.61531961e-5f); // -0x1.d70c12p-15 
        p = fmaf (p, t, -1.47697705e-4f); // -0x1.35be9ap-13 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  2.31468701e-3f); //  0x1.2f6402p-9 
        p = fmaf (p, t,  1.15392562e-2f); //  0x1.7a1e4cp-7 
        p = fmaf (p, t, -2.32015476e-1f); // -0x1.db2aeep-3 
        t = fmaf (p, t,  8.86226892e-1f); //  0x1.c5bf88p-1 
        r = fmaf (t, -a, t);
    } else {
        float p, q, s, t;
        t = (a >= 1.0f) ? (2.0f - a) : a;
        t = 0.0f - my_logf (t);
#if PORTABLE
        s = sqrtf (1.0f / t);
#else // PORTABLE
        s = sse_rsqrtf (t);
#endif // PORTABLE
        p =              2.23100796e+1f;  //  0x1.64f616p+4
        p = fmaf (p, s, -5.23008537e+1f); // -0x1.a26826p+5
        p = fmaf (p, s,  5.44409714e+1f); //  0x1.b3871cp+5
        p = fmaf (p, s, -3.35030403e+1f); // -0x1.0c063ap+5
        p = fmaf (p, s,  1.38580027e+1f); //  0x1.bb74c2p+3
        p = fmaf (p, s, -4.37277269e+0f); // -0x1.17db82p+2
        p = fmaf (p, s,  1.53075826e+0f); //  0x1.87dfc6p+0
        p = fmaf (p, s,  2.97993328e-2f); //  0x1.e83b76p-6
        p = fmaf (p, s, -3.71997419e-4f); // -0x1.86114cp-12
        p = fmaf (p, s, s);
#if PORTABLE
        r = 1.0f / p;
#else // PORTABLE
        r = sse_recipf (p);
        if (t == INFINITY) r = t;
#endif // PORTABLE
        if (a >= 1.0f) r = 0.0f - r;
    }
    return r;
}

/* Compute inverse of the CDF of the standard normal distribution.
   max ulp err = 4.08385
*/
float my_normcdfinvf (float a)
{
    return fmaf (-1.41421356f, my_erfcinvf (a + a), 0.0f);
}

/* natural logarithm. max ulp err = 0.85089 */
float my_logf (float a)
{
    float m, r, s, t, i, f;
    int32_t e;
    const float cutoff_f = 0.666666667f;
    if ((a > 0.0f) && (a <=  0x1.fffffep+127f)) { // 3.40282347e+38
        m = frexpf (a, &e);
        if (m < cutoff_f) {
            m = m + m;
            e = e - 1;
        }
        i = (float)e;
        f = m - 1.0f;
        s = f * f;
        /* Compute log1p(f) for f in [-1/3, 1/3] */
        r =             -0x1.0ae000p-3f;  // -0.130310059
        t =              0x1.208000p-3f;  //  0.140869141
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.f1988ap-4f); // -0.121483363
        t = fmaf (t, s,  0x1.1e5740p-3f); //  0.139814854
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.55b36ep-3f); // -0.166846141
        t = fmaf (t, s,  0x1.99d8b2p-3f); //  0.200120345
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.fffe02p-3f); // -0.249996200
        r = fmaf (t, f, r);
        r = fmaf (r, f,  0x1.5554fap-2f); //  0.333331972
        r = fmaf (r, f, -0x1.000000p-1f); // -0.500000000
        r = fmaf (r, s, f);
        r = fmaf (i, 0x1.62e430p-01f, r); //  0.693147182 // log(2)
    } else {
        r = a + a;  // silence NaNs if necessary
        if (a  < 0.0f) r = 0.0f/0.0f; // QNaN INDEFINITE
        if (a == 0.0f) r = -INFINITY; // -INF
    }
    return r;
}

float sse_recipf (float a)
{
    __m128 t;
    float e, r;
    t = _mm_set_ss (a);
    t = _mm_rcp_ss (t);
    _mm_store_ss (&r, t);
    e = fmaf (0.0f - a, r, 1.0f);
    e = fmaf (e, e, e);
    r = fmaf (e, r, r);
    return r;
}


float sse_rsqrtf (float a)
{
    __m128 t;
    float e, r;
    t = _mm_set_ss (a);
    t = _mm_rsqrt_ss (t);
    _mm_store_ss (&r, t);
    e = fmaf (0.0f - a, r * r, 1.0f);
    r = fmaf (fmaf (0.375f, e, 0.5f), e * r, r);
    return r;
}
```