# Calculate inverse CDF of distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I would like to use the distributions provided in [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) to compute an inverse CDF calculation. I see that normal distribution has the following method

```
template<class Generator>
result_type std::normal_distribution<RealType>::operator()(Generator& g);
```

where

> `g` - an uniform random bit generator object

My idea was to make a custom generator that simply passed a single value (the probability that I would like to look up the inverse `x` value for).

```
class ConstantGenerator
{
public:
    ConstantGenerator(double value) : m_value(value) {}
    double min() const { return 0.0; }
    double max() const { return 1.0; }
    double operator()(){ return m_value; }
    using result_type = double;
private:
    double m_value = 0.0;
};
```

Example usage would be

```
int main()
{
    std::normal_distribution<double> dist{10.0, 1.0};
    ConstantGenerator gen{0.5};
    std::cout << dist(gen);
}
```

[In this example](https://ideone.com/VBNLoH), I created a normal distribution with Mean=10, StdDev=1 therefore I was hoping that my `dist(gen)` call with passing `p=0.5` would return `10` (the mean) but instead it returns `1.46885`.

How can I modify my `ConstantGenerator` to use the existing C++11 distributions to perform inverse CDF calculations? Or am I incorrect in my assumption that `operator()` performs an inverse CDF in the first place?

Comment: For other dummies than me: CDF -> [Cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) ;-)

Comment: Generators in C++ are source of random BITS. There are no floats, doubles etc in generators, just bits typically packed into unsigned words

Comment: You might be thinking about distributions, what you put out looks like Dirac delta function distribution with PDF(x)=δ(x-0.5)

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question, but if you want to calculate the CDF of a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) you may need [std::erf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/erf) instead.

Comment: Possibly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60472139/computing-the-inverse-of-the-complementary-error-function-erfcinv-in-c), the answer to which includes a single-precision implementation of the inverse of the CDF of the standard normal distribution, a function called `my_normcdfinvf()`.

Comment: I was using the normal distribution as an example, but I was hoping to leverage any of the distributions available in the `<random>` header (normal, weibull, gamma, etc)

Answer (score 1):

`std::normal_distribution` is not a normal distribution function. Instead, it is a function that takes in random *bits* (like Severin Pappdeux already mentioned), and outputs *values* that are normally distributed. There is nothing in the standard that defines how the input bits are used.

A possible implementation of `std::normal_distribution` that I can think of is as follows: when you want a normally distributed value, it calls the random bit generator multiple times, assumes the output of that generator is distributed uniformly, then maps those outputs to the desired range of floating point values, and then just averages those values. You can see that this would not work as intended if you give it a generator that always gives the same value.

Another issue with your `ConstantGenerator` is that it doesn't follow the [requirements for UniformRandomBitGenerator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGenerator); in particular, the output should be an unsigned integer.

You can try to implement the [inverse CDF of the normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit#Computation) yourself.